# How to strip version folder from Windows Boost build?

Tags: boost, b2

I'm building Boost from source on linux and windows from a single python script, and notice the linux build places the headers under `<prefix>/include/boost/...`, whereas the windows builds add a version level `<prefix>/include/boost-1_74/boost/...`. Interestingly, this level does not appear for lib.

Running `diff` on both folders show no difference between them.

Looking at the `.\b2.exe --help` there is no mention of special behavior between windows and linux:

```
Targets and Related Options:

  install                 Install headers and compiled library files to the
  =======                 configured locations (below).

  --prefix=<PREFIX>       Install architecture independent files here.
                          Default: C:\Boost on Windows
                          Default: /usr/local on Unix, Linux, etc.

  --exec-prefix=<EPREFIX> Install architecture dependent files here.
                          Default: <PREFIX>

  --libdir=<LIBDIR>       Install library files here.
                          Default: <EPREFIX>/lib

  --includedir=<HDRDIR>   Install header files here.
                          Default: <PREFIX>/include
```

Where is this level coming from? How do I make it go away?

Comment: It looks like you are **installing** boost after building it. It is not a good idea.

Comment: @user7860670 I don't know what you are talking about.